Value in the input field is not retained by selenium java
This is the input for which i am struggling
<input id="totalProposalCost" name="totalProposalCost" class="input-field validateAmt " value="0" onblur="saveField(&#39;totalProposalCost&#39;)" type="text" value="0.0"/>
                                                        

The input field is disabled here, on writing the xpath from selectorshub it shows an alert saying "Input box is disable, enable it to enter value" i have used javascript executor to enable to box and enter the value but after saving the details and moving to the next page, the value is shown 0. in the console also there is not error.
I am trying to retain the value70000 but on moving to the next page it shows 0 there and in the previous page also.
This is my code:
This is my code:
        WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.id("totalProposalCost"));

    
        WebDriverWait w1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20));
        w1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(inputField));

        
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, 500);");
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled');", inputField);

        
        String valueToSet = "70000";
        js.executeScript(
                "arguments[0].value = arguments[1];" +
                "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));" +
                "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));" +
                "arguments[0].focus();" +  
                "arguments[0].blur();",   
                inputField, valueToSet
                );



That onblur works?! In any case: does it work if you do it manually (not via selenium)?

@Dave Newton, yes it works manually. please help

Can you [edit] your question and reduce the code to a [mcve]?

You can try to clear the original data by simulation the "back_space" key and don't use JS code to set the value.
The code like:
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    String value = String.valueOf(js.executeScript("return arguments[0].value;", element));
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)){
        for(int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++){
            element.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
        }
    }
    element.sendKeys(valueToSet);

